# why one security filter blocking to execute to another in Spring MVC-security app?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-rest

I am new to the Spring Security module. I would like to know what is the difference between two security filters?

```
<security:intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/newapi/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER','LOW_ADMIN')" />
<security:intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/newapi/user/*/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER,'BIG_ADMIN')" />
```

Also it seems that first security filters blocking to execute the second filter, because when I'm executing /newapi/user/data/7897896, only first security filter excuting, but it was expected me to execute the second security filters. Could anyone tell me why it's happening and how we can solve such issues?

FYI - We've very big/huge web application, which has nearly 150+ security filters define , so it's really getting difficult to debug such security related issue. Any Spring Security expert(s) can we've your thoughts here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<intercept-url>` rules are applied Top to Bottom. Therefore, this new  should be place before the original one or else it will be eclipse by the broad scope of /** path, so that is the reason your 2nd security filter not executing. You need to change sequences like below

```
<security:intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/newapi/user/*/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER,'BIG_ADMIN')" />
<security:intercept-url method="GET" pattern="/newapi/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER','LOW_ADMIN')" />
```